# How to define a type alias using a variable name

Tags: c++, typedef

I need to deﬁne a type alias, and I know that a variable is of the type I need an alias for. The explicit name for the type is not available. What can I do?

Comment: `using my_cool_alias_t = decltype(some_secret_variable);`

Comment: "The explicit name for the tpye is not available" what does that mean? Is it a lamdba? Can you show an example?

Comment: I don't know about that, some instructor in my uni asked me this question and I was like whoa... I appreciate the interest though.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two distinct types with the same name.

You *can* have types of the same name in different `namespace`s though.

Comment: title is misleading, question asks for type alias

Comment: Pls tell me a proper title for this question so I can change it? Nvm some ultra guy fixed it.